# Cant obtain spring tags on freemarker template

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

Code on freemarker template -

```
<#assign sForm=JspTaglibs["http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"]>
```

But I catch an exception when I go to the page

`Error executing FreeMarker template
FreeMarker template error:
Error while looking for TLD file for "http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"; see cause exception.
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: #assign sForm = JspTaglibs["http://ww...  [in template "login.ftl" at line 2, column 1]`

I already add dependencies - spring-security-taglibs.
Help please, thanks for future!

Comment: TLD-s are searched according the JSP 2.2 specification. In development- and embedded-servlet-container setups you may also need the "MetaInfTldSources" and "ClasspathTlds" freemarker.ext.servlet.FreemarkerServlet init-params or the similar system properites.)

Comment: Does the cause exception say anything interesting? Does the location of the TLD conform to the JSP 2.2 specification?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [freemarker.ext.jsp.EventForwarding](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_misc_servlet.html) listener

> FreeMarker does not rely on the JSP support of the servlet container in which it is run when it uses JSP taglibs since it implements its own lightweight JSP runtime environment. There is only one small detail to pay attention to: to enable the FreeMarker JSP runtime environment to dispatch events to JSP taglibs that register event listeners in their TLD files, you should add this to the WEB-INF/web.xml of your Web application:
>
> ```
> <listener>
>   <listener-class>freemarker.ext.jsp.EventForwarding</listener-class>
> </listener>
> ```

Comment: Did not help. Nothing has changed(